# Mounting a TV on a wooden wall stud with ~42cms of extension

Tags: drywall, mounting, television

I'm trying to mount a TV to a wall over a bed, and the best option we seem to have is a wooden stud in the drywall on the right side of it. Because of this, we want to use a mount that we can extend and rotate so that it's visible from the bed, similar to [this one](https://www.walmart.com/ip/VideoSecu-Articulating-TV-Wall-Mount-22-39-inch-VIZIO-D32hn-E1-D32f-E1-D32hn-E0-D39f-E1-D39hn-E0-D39h-D0-LCD-LED-HDTV-Swivel-Tilt-Bracket-WS2/47762905).

The TV is 40" and 9.3 kg.

[image]

The actual mount would extend about 42cms (16.5") out. We are worried about the stresses being too high on the screws and it coming out of the wall eventually. Is this a valid problem? Is there a way to manage this efficiently?

Comment: Would depend on size of TV and size of screws.  See they have another TV mount that covers two studs.  Pilot holes for screws needed to prevent splitting of wood stud.

Comment: @crip659 Sorry, forgot those details. The TV is 40" and 9.3 kg. We haven't yet chosen a mount, so the screws are up for debate. 
I don't think we have 2 studs relatively close to each other, but at the very least they are decently wide.

Comment: In most walls studs should at 16 inch on centre, a few at 24 inch on centre.  The answer below is a good idea also.  The bolts are called lag bolts(heavy duty screws).

Comment: I can't see your product link on this network, so I added an image based on a guess. Update if it's not right.

Answer (score 3):

JACK's idea is good, but I think you can get away with something more sleek. Just put a small plate of 3/4" board or plywood behind the mount to spread load. Something an inch beyond the mount plate all the way around would do (2" larger in height and width). This eliminates the high pressure points from the (possibly hollow) mount base and expands the surface area of the pressure.

Then, be sure to use screws of substantial diameter and length, properly piloted. The mount probably comes with options, but you'd want at least 1¼" of thread into the framing (but not more than about 1½" so you don't damage wiring or plumbing). I wouldn't go smaller than ¼" lag screw, and 5/16" is better, even if you have to drill out the mount a bit.

Comment: Paint the plywood after mounting it to match the wall, then mount the TV bracket. You'll hardly see the plywood.

Comment: Can't argue about sleek.

Answer (score 2):

A big concern and one I've witnessed is with the mounting bracket screwed tightly into the stud with drywall in between, after a while of use, the drywall becomes compressed and the bracket loosens up a bit. Sure, you can just tighten it up again but the drywall will continue to crumble.

My suggestion would be to get a 2"x 8" or 2"x 12" board  long enough to span across two studs and bolt it to both studs. Then bolt the bracket to the board. You want to make sure the bolts go into the center of each stud so a stud finder will be helpful. Also, make sure the actual bracket you get is sized right for the TV you will mount.

Comment: We also toyed with the idea of cutting out a small square of the drywall to get rid of this exact problem, would that solve that issue?

Also, when you way that we should bolt the bracket to the board, would that bolt then go through the drywall behind it as well? Because I assume you wouldn't bolt it to the edge where a stud is.

Comment: Don't hack up your wall. That's removing a tooth to fix a cavity. Just expand the load area somehow.

Comment: @GorbitGames Yes, you'd bolt the bracket to the board  between the studs.